# program flow in c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

in my WPF c# program I need to continuously monitor received bytes and transmitted bytes to CANBUS, through a PLC acting as a ProfiNet Master and working through a CANBUS bridge to converse with a multitude of devices.  My question is where does program flow go once the App.Run() method is executed within Main()?  I get that Activated and Startup events are raised, and therefore the handlers for those events are executed, but once the Startup event handler is executed, where does program control go?  I am asking to figure out where to put my own code which will run continuously until the App:Application is shut down.  I of course have multiple windows and pages which I display, and react to controls events for those windows and pages, but where is the background programming placed that runs awaiting those controls events?

Comment: Press the pause button and look at the calll stack 

Comment: `Application.Run()` starts and runs a messaging loop.  This loop runs continuously, dispatching messages to your app.  The messages can include internal (`Dispatcher` calls) and external (minimize clicked) sources.  This also includes the message to terminate (whether it's via clicking the close button, the kernel is shutting down, etc...).  `Application.Exit` uses this very queue to insert the message to terminate.

Comment: thank you for the message loop information.  that makes sense.  but you are implying that my only option in WPF is to define methods and event handlers which run as a result of events or messages.  my question remains, where do I put my continuously running code which monitors, for example, the received bytes counter from the CANBUS bridge that indicates there are received bytes to process?

Comment: I think the question is a bit too broad to be addressed here. You should put your code where it makes sense to put your code. As there is only a very vague description of your application, I have no idea what to suggest as making sense. That being said, most of the time, socket I/O is done on dedicated thread(s).

Comment: The answer to my question turns out to be DISPATCHER and BACKGROUNDWORKER.  Apparently WPF automatically creates a DISPATCHER class instance which executes UI operations in a FIFO manner.  And... there is also a BACKGROUNDWORKER class whose instance is automatically synchronized with the UI thread so as not to impact the UI operation (no delay in updates, no freezing of the UI).  Using methods of this class instance allows work to be done, that work progress to be monitored, and other good things.

Comment: if all I did was to create threads, in the Application_Startup function for example, then those threads could be doing continuous work, but they might impact the UI updates, and I would not have access to the UI controls (e.g charting, textbox updates, lisbox selections, etcetera).  I would have access to the global variables, and could use those to communicate with the controls... perhaps... but with DISPATCHER I have direct access.

Answer (score 0):

There is a single UI thread which will have to be used for all activities interacting with your WPF visual elements.  Typically you will have a constructor for a MainWindow which will be on this thread.

You can spawn a dedicated thread which will communicate with your external devices and provide a listener to monitor external communications which aren't directly related to the WPF framework.

Comment: I actually removed the "StartURI" component of App.xaml, which would normally point at "MainWindow" and substituted the "Startup" component pointing to my custom "Application_Startup" event handler in order to try to force the program flow to go somewhere where I could add background code.  But I think that it is not a good thing to have continuously running code in an event handler... something which is meant to run quickly and then exit.  So the question remains... when my application is running and not servicing any of the UI controls, where is its control?

Comment: @TonySimkus, "_where is its control?_" This is not answerable unless you precisely define what you mean with "control". An application can have several threads (most non-console apps do), with each thread having its own control-flow, so to speak. With regard to the main/UI thread, it is in the dispatcher/message loop, as Zer0's comment underneath your question already explained.